# Use jQuery to show user score after user answers a list of questions with radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list of questions in HTML. Each question will have 4 radio buttons for the answers, and the user will select the appropriate answer. Each radio button has an assigned value. At the end, I would like to show in HTML, the user's score once the questions have all been answered.

It's fairly straight forward, but I am having issues iterating through the questions and returning a summing the total value for their score.

Any suggestions on the iterating jQuery loops would be helpful.

```
<div>
          <p class="question">1. Question:</p>        
            <ul id="answers1">            
              <input type="radio" name="q1" value="15" id="q1a"><label for="q1a"> Answer 1</label><br/>      
              <input type="radio" name="q1" value="10" id="q1b"><label for="q1b"> Answer 2</label><br/>            
              <input type="radio" name="q1" value="5" id="q1c"><label for="q1c"> Answer 3</label><br/>            
              <input type="radio" name="q1" value="1" id="q1d"><label for="q1d"> Answer 4</label><br/>       
            </ul>        

          <p class="question">2. Question</p>        
            <ul id="answers2">            
              <input type="radio" name="q2" value="15" id="q2a"><label for="q2a"> Answer 1</label><br/>       
              <input type="radio" name="q2" value="10" id="q2b"><label for="q2b"> Answer 2</label><br/>            
              <input type="radio" name="q2" value="5" id="q2c"><label for="q2c"> Answer 3</label><br/>           
              <input type="radio" name="q2" value="1" id="q2d"><label for="q2d"> Answer 4</label><br/>       
            </ul>        

          <p class="question">3. Question</p>        
            <ul id="answers3">            
              <input type="radio" name="q3" value="1" id="q3a"><label for="q3a">Answer 1</label><br/>            
              <input type="radio" name="q3" value="5" id="q3b"><label for="q3b">Answer 2</label><br/>            
              <input type="radio" name="q3" value="10" id="q3c"><label for="q3c">Answer 3</label><br/>           
              <input type="radio" name="q3" value="15" id="q3d"><label for="q3d">Answer 4</label><br/>       
            </ul>        

          <div id="sum" >Print Score from Questions Here</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What Jquery code do you have already? What have you tried?

Comment: Hope this helps you.

Comment: @Simon I keep messing with it and it's nothing that even remotely works. so I didn't post it. I will post something soon.

Comment: @Simon - this is what I have now    $(function(){
 for(i=0;i<7;i++){
  investorRisk("answers" + i);
 }
 
 $("#sum").html(sum);
});

function investorRisk(answerId)
{
 var listItems = $("#" + answerId + " input");
 listItems.each(function(idx, input){
  if(input.checked){
   sum += parseInt(input.value);
  }
 });
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get total score usong this.

```
  var score=0;
$("input[type='radio']:checked").each(function () {
 score += $(this).val();
 });

$('#sum').text(score);
```

Comment: @Kane. This should be the accepted answer. So simple!

Comment: @RemyaJ. Done. My upvotes don't get posted as I don't have enough reputation yet.